# Redirect registration url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect registration page to homepage by using `.htaccess` now my code is redirecting to some strange location on the server and displaying "Page isn't working" message. However I would like it to redirect to homepage. How it is possible and what I need to edit? I guess `index.php`?

```
# RewriteBase /

# Disable calls to user registration ("register", this url ends with: view=registration))
# Send all blocked request to homepage, use Flag [F] for 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (view=registration) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R]

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: To which page is it currently redirecting?

Comment: Did you try `RewriteRule .* /index.php` ?

Comment: This one giving: "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@ to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting **Page isn't working** error message because your rule redirects `/index.php` back to itself . Your catch-all regex pattern `^(.*)$` also matches the destination URI `/index.php` . You need to fix it so that the Rule's pattern can not match the destination path.

You can either use a `RewriteCond` or change your regex to `((?!index\.php).*)$`  .

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (view=registration) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?index\.php).*)$ index.php [R]
```